# Sidekiq - Enqueued Job is running from old code

Tags: ruby-on-rails, sidekiq

I have about 30 sidekiq jobs scheduled in the future (let's days 1 in a day for the next 30 days).

I use capistrano for deployment. So I have 5 release directories at anytime. Let's say:

```
/var/www/release1/ (recent)
/var/www/release2/
/var/www/release3/
/var/www/release4/
/var/www/release5/
```

Let's say after few days, I make a new release. Now, the previously scheduled jobs are still running from the old code. Is this expected? How can we fix this to ensure that it uses the latest release directory when it starts running rather than when it is scheduled?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This could be because sidekiq process didn't restart after a successful deployment.

Make sure your deployment process restarts sidekiq and make sure restart actually works, otherwise sidekiq processes are still holding on to old code.

https://github.com/mperham/sidekiq/wiki/Deployment

Answer (score 7):

I'd just like to contribute with an alternate answer for someone who might get into this situation by other reason.

It happened to me that there was a **sidekiq zombie process** running. So, even if I would stop sidekiq manually and restart it, I had another sidekiq process hanging running with old code. Therefore, it's a good idea to run unix `htop` command or `ps aux | grep sidek` and try to look for zombie processes.

Comment: how select id number of process given by `ps aux | grep sidek` to kill it in same cmd line?